# Loader UI takes time to go off even after I receive the response

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

In the start I have called active function of loaderservice and passed true
And after making the service call 'uploadFile' , inside if I check for progress and when 100 I again set active function of loaderservice to false.
The issue is the loader goes off but takes time.

Component using loader service

```
 this.loaderService.active(true);
 this.fileUploadService.uploadFile(file, this.siteRef, 
 this.floorRef).subscribe(res => {
    if (res.progress === 100) {
      this.loaderService.active(false);
      this.isUploadProgress = false;
      this.alertService.success('Floor plan uploaded successfully');
    }
```

loader.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { LoaderService } from '@/shared/_services';

@Component({
  selector: 'fs-loader',
  template: `<div 
            *ngIf="state" 
            class="overlay-loader loader">
           </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.scss']
 })

export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private subscription: Subscription;
state: any =  false;

constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.loaderService.getState().subscribe(message => { 
        this.state = message; 
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

closeErrorDialog() {
    this.state = null; 
}
}
```

loader.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoaderService {
 private subject = new Subject<any>();
 private keepAfterNavigationChange = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            if (this.keepAfterNavigationChange) {
                this.keepAfterNavigationChange = false;
            } else {
                this.subject.next();
            }
        }
    });
 }

  active(isActive: Boolean, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
    this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
    this.subject.next(isActive);
 }

 inactive(isActive: Boolean, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
    this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
    this.subject.next(isActive);
 }

 getState(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
 }
}
```

My query is even after receiving response and setting the loader false why it appears for a longer time before being removed. Can this issue be resolved.

Comment: Have you tried `this.subject.complete()` after you yield the state?

Comment: @DaniR I havent tried, could you please explain where and why we should use it, thanks alot!